# matching line with spaces, Sed

Tags: bash, sed, match, line, space

Hi im trying to match this line with sed and remove or append the '#':

```
ContType is MOMENTUM
```

My Code:

```
sed -i '' "s/#ContType\sis\sMomentum/ContType\sis\sMomentum/g" FlameMaster.input
```

I tried to escape the spaces with \s.

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: just removing or appending the # at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to delete this row;

```
sed  -i '/ContType is MOMENTUM/d' yourFile
```

to append #

```
sed -i '/ContType is MOMENTUM/ s/^/#/' yourFile
```

Comment: you could also use `s/ContType is MOMENTUM/#\0/`

Answer (score 0):

Ok cool found a solution:

```
sed -i '' "s/ContType\(.*MOMENTUM\)/#ContType\1/g" FlameMaster.input
```

this is matching the ContType line only if there is a MOMENTUM in the same line.